# space between signature line and regards — increase available space between footer and text

Tags: spacing, header-footer, letters, signatures

I'm going to submit a cover letter and I found this formula and style for closing which I quite like; however, for some reason, I cannot force the space between the signature line and the regards to be bigger.

Ideally, this would also mean to reduce the empty space between the main text and the footer; does anyone has any idea on how to do so? Thanks in advance!

FYI I'm using the package `fancyhdr`

See the snippet below for a better understanding of the issue
[image]

And code used

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[inkscapearea=page]{svg} 

\usepackage[
    letterpaper,
    margin=1in,
    headsep=.5in,
    footskip=.5in,
    showframe
]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=green,
    linkcolor=teal,
    urlcolor=coolblack,
    linktoc=all
}
\definecolor{teal}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.5}
\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
\hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth
\vskip 2pt
\hrule\@height.5pt\@width\headwidth
\vskip-\headrulewidth
\vskip-1.5pt}}
\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{subsequentpages}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
}

\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{firstpage}}
\pagestyle{subsequentpages}

\usepackage{tabto,ulem,booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

...

\begin{flushright}
    Sincerely yours,\\
    \hfill
    Signature: \parbox[t]{.5\linewidth}{\rule[-3pt]{\linewidth}{.4pt}}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Comment: after `Sincerely yours,` and before `\hfill` add `\vspace{\baselineskip}` -- the `\baselineskip` can be in multiples such as `2\baselineskip` or `1.5\baselineskip` etc - looks like this -- `Sincerely yours,\\
  \vspace{1.5\baselineskip}
  \hfill`

Comment: @jsbibra Indeed, thank you so much; however, now I have the problem of this whole signature block to be in the next page on its own. I need to keep the document in one page...

Comment: EDIT, sorry stupid question. I simply fixed/reduced the bottom margin. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the comments into MWE -- in case it meets the requirement do accept the answer with a green tick mark and also upvote

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[inkscapearea=page]{svg} 

\usepackage[
letterpaper,
margin=1in,
headsep=.5in,
footskip=.5in,
showframe
]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=green,
    linkcolor=teal,
    urlcolor=coolblack,
    linktoc=all
}
\definecolor{teal}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.5}
\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
        \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth
        \vskip 2pt
        \hrule\@height.5pt\@width\headwidth
        \vskip-\headrulewidth
        \vskip-1.5pt}}
\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{subsequentpages}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
}

\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{firstpage}}
\pagestyle{subsequentpages}

\usepackage{tabto,ulem,booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{flushright}
        Sincerely yours,\\      
        \vspace{1.5\baselineskip}       
        \hfill
        Signature: \parbox[t]{.5\linewidth}{\rule[-3pt]{\linewidth}{.4pt}}
    \end{flushright}
    
\end{document}
```